# Creating HTML UI tag using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I want to create an `LI` tag using C# a follows:

```
<li>
    <a class="thumb" name="leaf" href="Images/Image0.jpg" title="Image 0">
        <img src="Images/Image0Thumb.jpg" alt="Image 0" />
    </a>
    <div class="caption">
        <div class="image-title">Image 0</div>
        <div class="image-desc">Description for image 0</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

And then add it to an existing `UL` tag. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`LiteralControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx) class to create that kind of hierarchy and than append it into your `ul` tag as a content.

Comment: The literal control is good if you won to render the html inside him. If you like to append controls the place holder is better.